# Why does this not compile?

Tags: document-classes

I have no clue why my code is not compiling, it's a long code and I don't know if the problem is before the `\begin{document}` or after. Thank you for reading, here is the code:

**The main error I think it is: Argument of \language@active@arg~ has an extra }.**

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 1pt]{book}
\usepackage{lmodern}
% matemáticas:
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb} 
% idioma:
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel} % 'cuadro' es el título del caption de table por defecto siguiendo indicaciones de RAE; es-tabla lo cambia a 'tabla'
% gestión de párrafos (hace innecesario indicar el salto de línea con doble barra y elimina el indent de todos los párrafos):
\usepackage{parskip}
% enlaces a URLs:
\usepackage{hyperref}
% gráficos:
\usepackage{graphicx, wrapfig, subcaption}
% tablas:
\usepackage{array, multirow}

\newcommand{\dl}{\left(}
\newcommand{\dr}{\right)}

\newcommand{\dsin}[1]{\sin{\left(#1\right)}}
\newcommand{\dtan}[1]{\tan{\left(#1\right)}}
\newcommand{\dcos}[1]{\cos{\left(#1\right)}}
\newcommand{\dsec}[1]{\sec{\left(#1\right)}}
\newcommand{\dcsc}[1]{\csc{\left(#1\right)}}
\newcommand{\dcot}[1]{\cot{\left(#1\right)}}
\newcommand{\darcsin}[1]{\arcsin{\left(#1\right)}}
\newcommand{\darccos}[1]{\arccos{\left(#1\right)}}
\newcommand{\darctan}[1]{\arctan{\left(#1\right)}}
\newcommand{\dsinh}[1]{\sinh{\left(#1\right)}}
\newcommand{\dcosh}[1]{\cosh{\left(#1\right)}}
\newcommand{\dtanh}[1]{\tanh{\left(#1\right)}}

\newcommand{\dln}[1]{\ln{\left(#1\right)}}

\newcommand{\dsum}[2]{\displaystyle\sum_{#1}^{#2}}
\newcommand{\dlim}[2]{\lim_{#1\rightarrow#2}}
\newcommand{\dint}[2]{\displaystyle\int_{#1}^{#2}}
\newcommand{\doint}[2]{\displaystyle\oint_{#1}^{#2}}


\NewDocumentCommand{\umathnote}{ mm }
   {
     \overset % ❶
        {% The annotation goes above
          \textcolor{black!20!white}{\hbox to 0pt{\hss % ❷
             $ % return to math mode
               \begin{array}{c} % ❸
                   \displaystyle #2\\ % ❹
                   \Big\downarrow % ❺
               \end{array}
             $
          \hss}
          }
        }
        {#1} % 
   }
   
\NewDocumentCommand{\dmathnote}{ mm }
   {
     \underset % ❶
        {% The annotation goes above
          \textcolor{black!20!white}{\hbox to 0pt{\hss % ❷
             $ % return to math mode
               \begin{array}{c} % ❸
                   \Big\uparrow\\ % ❹
                   \displaystyle #2 % ❺
               \end{array}
             $
          \hss}
          }
        }
        {#1} % 
   }


\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.5}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
            {-2.5ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.25ex}%
            {1.25ex \@plus .25ex}%
            {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4} % how many sectioning levels to assign numbers to
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}    % how many sectioning levels to show in ToC

\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, arrows}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
\newenvironment{grand}
{\begin{center}\large}
{\end{center}}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}


\newcounter{dem}[chapter]\setcounter{dem}{0}
\renewcommand{\thedem}{\Roman{dem}}  
\newenvironment{dem}[2][]{%
\refstepcounter{dem}%
\ifstrempty{#1}%
{\mdfsetup{%
frametitle={%
\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
\node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=white]
{\strut Tema~\thedem};}}
}%
{\mdfsetup{%
frametitle={%
\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
\node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=white]
{\begin{minipage}{0.99\linewidth}#1\end{minipage}};}}%
}%
\mdfsetup{innertopmargin=10pt,linecolor=black,%
linewidth=0.5pt,topline=true,%
frametitleaboveskip=\dimexpr-\ht\strutbox\relax
}
\begin{mdframed}[]\relax%
\label{#2}}{\end{mdframed}}


\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{most}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,
              number within=chapter,
              list inside=ej
              ]{ej}[1][]{%
    enhanced, breakable,
    title={{\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\textbf{Ejercicio}~\thetcbcounter.~\textit{#1}\end{minipage}}},
    halign title=left,
    sharp corners,
    colback=white,
    coltitle=black,
    colbacktitle=white,
    boxrule=0pt,frame hidden,
    underlay unbroken and first={%
         \ifnumequal{\tcbsegmentstate}{0}{
            \draw[black,double] (interior.north west)--(interior.south west);
        }{\ifnumequal{\tcbsegmentstate}{1}{
                \draw[black,double] (interior.north west)--(segmentation.west);
            \begin{tcbclipinterior}
                    \draw[help lines, step=3.8mm, black!20!white](segmentation.south west) grid (frame.south east);
            \end{tcbclipinterior}
        }{\ifnumequal{\tcbsegmentstate}{2}{
            \begin{tcbclipinterior}
                    \draw[help lines, step=3.8mm, black!20!white](interior.north west) grid (interior.south east);
            \end{tcbclipinterior}
        }}}
    },
    underlay middle and last={%
         \ifnumequal{\tcbsegmentstate}{0}{
            \draw[black,double] (interior.north west)--(interior.south west);
        }{\ifnumequal{\tcbsegmentstate}{1}{
                \draw[black,double] (interior.north west)--(segmentation.west);
            \begin{tcbclipinterior}
                    \draw[help lines, step=3.8mm, black!20!white](segmentation.south west) grid (frame.south east);
            \end{tcbclipinterior}
        }{\ifnumequal{\tcbsegmentstate}{2}{
            \begin{tcbclipinterior}
                    \draw[help lines, step=3.8mm, black!20!white](interior.north west) grid (interior.south east);
            \end{tcbclipinterior}
        }}}
    },
    boxed title style={%
      colframe=white, 
      boxrule=0pt,
      colback=white,
      left=0pt,
      right=0pt},
    attach boxed title to top left={xshift={-5pt}},
    lower separated=false, 
    before lower = {\tcbsubtitle[colback=white, opacityback=0, colframe=black, opacityframe=0, boxrule=1pt, height=1cm,  width=2.55cm, valign=center]{\textbf{Solution:}}}
}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,
              number within=chapter,
              list inside=defi
              ]{defi}[1][]{%
    enhanced,
    title={{\begin{minipage}{0.99\linewidth}\textit{#1}\end{minipage}}},
    ,
    halign title=left,
    sharp corners,
    colback=white,
    coltitle=black,
    colbacktitle=white,
    boxrule=0pt,frame hidden,
    overlay unbroken={%
      \draw[black,double] (interior.north west)--(interior.south west);%
      },
    boxed title style={%
      colframe=white, 
      boxrule=0pt,
      colback=white,
      left=0pt,
      right=0pt},
    attach boxed title to top left={xshift={-5pt}},
}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage[bottom=0.5cm,top=0.5cm,right=0.5cm,left=0.5cm,binding=0.5cm]{geometry}



\begin{document}

\begin{dem}[Estructura cristalina]{}

 
 
 
 
 
\underset{\text{Átomos en volumen}}{\footnotesize\fbox{$N_{a_V}=\dfrac{N_A\rho V}{M_{mol}}$}}
\underset{\text{~}}{\footnotesize\fbox{$S=4\pi r^2$}}
\underset{\text{~}}{\footnotesize\fbox{$V=\dfrac{4}{3}\pi r^3$}}
\underset{\text{Densidad celda}}{\footnotesize\fbox{$\rho=\dfrac{N\cdot M_A}{V_c\cdot N_A}$}}
\underset{\text{~}}{\footnotesize\fbox{$~$}}
\underset{\text{~}}{\footnotesize\fbox{$~$}}
\underset{\text{~}}{\footnotesize\fbox{$~$}}
\underset{\text{~}}{\footnotesize\fbox{$~$}}
\underset{\text{~}}{\footnotesize\fbox{$~$}}
\underset{\text{~}}{\footnotesize\fbox{$~$}}


\end{dem}

\begin{dem}[Red recíproca{}

\underset{\text{~}}{\footnotesize\fbox{$~$}}
\underset{\text{~}}{\footnotesize\fbox{$~$}}
\underset{\text{~}}{\footnotesize\fbox{$~$}}
\underset{\text{~}}{\footnotesize\fbox{$~$}}
\underset{\text{~}}{\footnotesize\fbox{$~$}}
\underset{\text{~}}{\footnotesize\fbox{$~$}}
\underset{\text{~}}{\footnotesize\fbox{$~$}}
\underset{\text{~}}{\footnotesize\fbox{$~$}}
\underset{\text{~}}{\footnotesize\fbox{$~$}}
\underset{\text{~}}{\footnotesize\fbox{$~$}}
\underset{\text{~}}{\footnotesize\fbox{$~$}}
\underset{\text{~}}{\footnotesize\fbox{$~$}}

\end{dem}

\begin{dem}[Estructura cristalina y difracción de rayos X]{}
\underset{\text{~}}{\footnotesize\fbox{$~$}}
\underset{\text{~}}{\footnotesize\fbox{$~$}}
\underset{\text{~}}{\footnotesize\fbox{$~$}}
\underset{\text{~}}{\footnotesize\fbox{$~$}}
\underset{\text{~}}{\footnotesize\fbox{$~$}}
\underset{\text{~}}{\footnotesize\fbox{$~$}}
\end{dem}

\begin{dem}[Propiedades mecánicas y térmicas]{}
\underset{\text{~}}{\footnotesize\fbox{$~$}}
\underset{\text{~}}{\footnotesize\fbox{$~$}}
\underset{\text{~}}{\footnotesize\fbox{$~$}}
\underset{\text{~}}{\footnotesize\fbox{$~$}}
\underset{\text{~}}{\footnotesize\fbox{$~$}}
\underset{\text{~}}{\footnotesize\fbox{$~$}}
\end{dem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `a4paper, 1pt]{book}` book does not have a `1pt` option `\newcommand{\dsin}[1]{\sin{\left(#1\right)}}` this will make bad spacing, you should not have `{` after `\sin` and should use `\left-\right` vary sparingly and probably never with trig functions. `\newcommand{\dsum}[2]{\displaystyle\sum_{#1}^{#2}}` will make _all_ the following expression displaystyle not just this sum,

Comment: You should load several packages like `titlesec` *before* `hyperref`, because `hyperref` needs to patch those packages and currently can do this only, if `hyperref` is loaded after those packages.

Comment: the error  is `! Package keyval Error: binding undefined`  because you have `binding=0.5cm]{geometry}` and there is no such option

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I fixed and it still not compiling but that fixed an error

Comment: @cabohah that never make my documents not compile, but I will fixed

Comment: You really  should provide a more reasonable test file, can you not reproduce the error you are asking about with less than 268 lines and over 20 packages?

Comment: `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.5}` ???? would make the document unreadable, delete this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more reasonable version of your test file (after fixing the call to `geometry` with undefined `binding` option) would be

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\underset{\text{Átomos en volumen}}{\footnotesize\fbox{$N_{a_V}=\dfrac{N_A\rho V}{M_{mol}}$}}

\end{document}
```

Which gives

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Command \footnotesize invalid in math mode on input line 6.


! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.6 ...fbox{$N_{a_V}=\dfrac{N_A\rho V}{M_{mol}}$}}
                                                  
?
```

Because `\footnotsize` is not allowed in math and `\underset` must be in math, so this runs with no error

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$\underset{\text{Átomos en volumen}}{\fbox{$N_{a_V}=\dfrac{N_A\rho V}{M_{\mathrm{mol}}}$}}$

\end{document}
```

If you fix the multiple instances of that error, so `\underset` is in math, your test file resolves to

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$\underset{\text{~}}{\fbox{$~$}}$

\end{document}
```

Which produces

```
! Argument of \language@active@arg~ has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.7 $\underset{\text{~}}{\fbox{$~$}}
                                    $
?
```

As Spanish babel makes `~` a shorthand so `~n` is ñ

You could disable shorthands but `~` does nothing useful here as there can be no line breaking so you can use a normal space.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$\underset{\text{ }}{\fbox{ }}$

\end{document}
```

Produces no error (although it is a very weird construction)